# Python inplace parameter failed when trying to replace some values of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, in-place

I have the following dataframe:

```
2010-01-04 00:00:00 2.874   2.947   2.838   2.91    3609000 0

2010-01-05 00:00:00 2.947   3.118   2.947   3.1    13559646 0

2010-01-06 00:00:00 3.118   3.163   2.974   3.046   5836795 0

2010-01-07 00:00:00 3.055   3.064   2.956   2.974   4132464 0
```

And when I execute the codes:

```
(df[((df.index >= '2010-01-04 00:00:00') & (df.index <= '2010-01-07 00:00:00'))]).replace(2.874,0,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

The value (2.874) in the first row and first column still remain 2.874 instead of the new value, 0. May I know what I did wrong please?

Comment: This is most likely a floating point issue, and the value `2.874` which you see is not _exactly_ that value.